# mysql select true if... statement satisfies two criteria

Tags: mysql

I have a table with a boolean value and I want to find out if a group of id's have both values.

This sql selects the group of products I want to test:

```
SELECT 
  cp.ItemID,
  cp.IsUnitsOfMeasure
from grouped_products gp
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id = gp.product_id
LEFT JOIN c_products cp ON cp.ItemID = p.product_id
WHERE gp.group_id=123
```

I want to find out if cp.IsUnitsOfMeasure for the group contains both 1 and 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT   gp.group_id,
         SUM(cp.IsUnitsOfMeasure=0) AND SUM(cp.IsUnitsOfMeasure=1) AS ContainsBoth,
FROM     grouped_products AS gp
  LEFT JOIN products      AS  p USING (product_id)
  LEFT JOIN c_products    AS cp ON cp.ItemID = p.product_id
GROUP BY gp.group_id
```

`ContainsBoth` will be `TRUE` or `FALSE` to indicate whether or not each respective group contains *both* a `c_product` with `IsUnitsOfMeasure=0` *and* another with `=1`.

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
SELECT 
    cp.ItemID,
    SUM(cp.IsUnitsOfMeasure) AS sum,
    COUNT(cp.IsUnitsOfMeasure) AS count,
    from grouped_products gp
LEFT JOIN products p ON p.product_id = gp.product_id
LEFT JOIN c_products cp ON cp.ItemID = p.product_id
WHERE gp.group_id=123
```

- if `sum` is equal to `count` then all the lines are to 1
- if `sum` is equal to 0 then all the lines are to 0
- in all other cases: you have both 1 and 0 in the group

Comment: Thank you, this answer is actually more useful for me although the other answer was more related to what I actually asked for.